# Using 'find -exec' to remove directories works incorrectly with git filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am removing a bunch of accidentally-committed node modules from a git repository. To do this, I need to remove all directories named 'node_modules' from every commit. I don't know the directories' file paths, so I am using `find` to locate and remove them. This command does what I want to `HEAD`:

```
find . -name node_modules -type d -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

However, when I attempt to use it with git filter-branch, it not only deletes the 'node_modules' directories, but also complete file subtrees containing them. That is, if I run this:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'find . -name node_modules -type d -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;'
```

from the base directory of a repository that looks like this:

```
./node_modules/
./x/node_modules/
./y/z/node_modules/
./a/
```

the result will be this:

```
./a/
```

even though I want it to be this:

```
./x/
./y/z/
./a/
```

Is this a known limitation of git filter-branch, or am I doing something wrong?

Note: I know that the [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) would typically be better than `git filter-branch` for deleting all directories with the same name, but I do not have Java on my platform.

Note #2: I also know it might be better to use git index-filter. I haven't looked into this too much because I am building a larger script to pass to git filter-branch, and there are other commands in the script that will only work with git tree-filter.

Comment: Sorry to hear you can't use the BFG due to the lack of Java! Out of curiosity, what platform are you using?

Comment: I'm on a corporate server without Java installed. It's not a technical issue, it's a company policy issue.